# Best practises for creating datasets for the purpose of finetuning LLMs

Tags: nlp, dataset, llm, reference-request

I am working on a problem for which no datasets exist. I have obtained several examples from this domain, and so far have been using them in Large Language Model (LLM) prompts(few shot learning) but I noticed results are not good and perhaps finetuning is the way to go. The expected output of LLM is to generate text and logical formulas.

I am looking for tutorials that include best practises for the following and more:

1. How to decide which fields (columns) to include?
2. What types of data to include as input?

Any pointers is extremely appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "fields" and "types of data"? LLMs are trained and fine-tuned on raw text. I think more information is needed to understand your use case.

Comment: @noe please see an example (https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/fine-tuning-large-language-models). There are 4 fields in the dataset. Label is 0/1 and the rest are text. I am looking for best practises to teach me why for example, these specific 4 columns were chosen?

Comment: The four columns are just what happen to come with the dataset. They use text and labels because they are specifically training a text classification model. It's not a model predicting text, it's a model that maps input text to specific classes.